# Where can I find JSpec maven info

Tags: activejdbc, jspec

Having used RSpec in the past, I would like to use JSpec in my Java project. But I am unable to find  install information in Maven Central repository or in [JSpec](http://javalite.io/jspec).  Would appreciate little direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is part of the JavaLite Common Package. You can find it in Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22javalite-common%22

Comment: Thank you. I have added dependency but not sure which package to import. Is it `org.javalite.test.jspec.JSpec`? Even tried `org.javalite.test.*` but couldn;t find methods such as `..shouldBeEqual...`

Comment: You can look here: http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/org/javalite/test/jspec/JSpec.html
The package is: 
`org.javalite.test.jspec.JSpec`

Here is the working code example: https://github.com/javalite/simple-example/blob/master/src/test/java/activejdbc/examples/simple/EmployeeSpec.java

Comment: I added a section to the bottom of this page for convenience: http://javalite.io/jspec

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use JSpec with Cucumber-Jvm. Would love to see just one example at `javalite.io/jspec`.